# Load script when flipbook page is turned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working on a flipbook, and im trying to make my script load when second pages is visible. What i have tried right now is

With `if ($('#bubble').is(':visible'))`  added the bubble script still loads even when i am not on the right page.

Javascript

```
if ($('#bubble').is(':visible')) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.small').fadeOut(1);
            $('.small').removeClass('hidden');
            $(".small").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.big').fadeOut(1);
            $('.big').removeClass('hidden');
            //  $('.big').fadeIn(1500);
            $(".big").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.test').fadeOut(1);
            $('.test').removeClass('hidden');
            $(".test").delay(3000).fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="bb-item" id="bubble">
  <img class="fixedsize" src="images/1.png" alt="image02" /></a>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="oval-thought">
      <p>Text inside bubble</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small">.</div>
  <div class="big">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're encountering? Can you describe what's *not working*, please? Are there any errors?

Comment: edited my post, thanks. @wahwahwah

Comment: what is "the bubble script"? Are you talking about the text "Text inside bubble"?

Comment: @imjared text inside bubble is the text inside.. the script is for fading a text bubble. i want this fade to happen when i flip my page

Comment: @Petersson - this shouldnt be a big problem, but unfortunately I can't tell what it is *exactly* problematic here. Meaning, I don't see any code or html about "pages" or a flipbook so it's really difficult (if not impossible) to tell what's wrong. From your description, you need a way in code to check what page is "active" before you make your script visible. Also, you do not need to call `$(document).ready()` more than once.